# BeautifulSoup and Lists

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to use beautifulsoup to look through and request each url in a txt file. So far I am able to scrape the first link for what I seek, progressing to the next url I hit an error.

This is the error I keep getting:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're
> probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you
> call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import constants as c

file = open(c.fvtxt)
read = file.readlines()
res = []
DOMAIN = c.vatican_domain
pdf = []


def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in read:
    bs = get_soup(link)
    res.append(bs)
    soup = bs.find('div', {'class': 'headerpdf'})
    pdff = soup.find('a')
    li = pdff.get('href')
    surl = f"{DOMAIN}{li}"
    pdf.append(f"{surl}\n")
    print(pdf)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the text file if the data are not confidential?

Comment: Yes, these are the working links from what I scraped:

https://www.vatican.va/index.htm
https://www.vatican.va/holy_father/pius_xi/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_29091932_acerba-animi_en.html
https://www.vatican.va/holy_father/pius_x/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_15041905_acerbo-nimis_en.html
https://www.vatican.va/holy_father/pius_xii/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061958_ad-apostolorum-principis_en.html
https://www.vatican.va/holy_father/benedict_xv/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xv_enc_01111914_ad-beatissimi-apostolorum_en.html

Comment: The first link is not useful, the following links are useful, I am able to get the first line but then I hit the AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your variable name confuses the Python interpreter, you cannot have the same name as a function and a variable at the same time, in your case 'bs'.

It should work fine if you rename the variable `bs` to `parsed_text` or something else but `bs`.

```
for link in read:
    parsed_text = get_soup(link)
    res.append(parsed_text)
    soup = parsed_text.find('div', {'class': 'headerpdf'})
    pdff = soup.find('a')
    li = pdff.get('href')
    print(li)
    surl = f"{DOMAIN}{li}"
    pdf.append(f"{surl}\n")
    print(pdf)
```

The result:

[image]